# Why do power companies never bother residential customers about power factors?

Tags: power, power-factor-correction

I recently bought a Kill-a-Watt meter to measure power consumption of my devices. This was just a fun project for me. I put this on my Mac-Mini to see power consumption during various usage states - idle, MATLAB bench mark, starting an application, screen-saver etc. and discovered that the power factor my my Mac-Mini was 0.2 when on standby and .80+ when up and running. However, while shutting down and before login the power factor was .45

I also measured this for my:

```
Raspberry pi with a 5v 3A power supply (PF=0.68)
Dell Laptop 90W charger (PF=.98)
2006 Compaq Charger (PF=.55)
CFL Table Lamps (PF=.52)
Tube CFL Lamps (PF=.55)
Power PC Late 2005 (PF=)
A 40W Audio Amplifier (PF=.66)
Vacuum cleaner (PF=.97)
Samsung phone charger (PF=.58).
```

From what I learned in my classes, 0.9+ is a good power factor and utility companies fine industries if they have power factors less than this. But most household equipment seem to have terrible power factors. Yet I have never heard of utility companies fining residential users? Why? Do they correct the power factors at the transformers at our residence? Or is residential usage too meager to bother about?

Comment: the above power factor measurement of various switching power supplies reveals that they are not equipped with PFC circuit

Comment: You've probably forgot to include the PF for *Power PC Late 2005*.

Comment: Yes I did :-) I am yet to measure it. I suspect it will be poor.

Comment: Are the power factors you are measuring due to inductive or capacitive loading?  Typically industrial companies have heavily inductive loading (e.g. motors) whereas I would suspect the devices you list might tend more to the capacitive side.

Comment: I would think the first stage of an SMPS or a power supply would be a transformer - inductive. I may be wrong.

Comment: @Michael DC power supplies often have poor power factor because they present a non-linear load due to the rectifier and smoothing capacitor.

Comment: @Lord Loh: Of SMPS? RoTFL. A transformer first-stage in SMPS would negate its titular advantage (switching mode).

Comment: The Kill-a-Watt meter measures up to 1875 VA, but when used for small loads with less than 100 W only, the precision of measurement is low. The influence of small loads to the precision of power factor is not kown. I would measure the power factor for some pure resistive loads like incadescent bulbs and electric kettles with different power ratings. The power factor of smaller and larger pure resistive loads should be very close to 1.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The power factor of residential premises is already pretty good.

From a [2002 report](http://www.abcb.gov.au/~/media/Files/Download%20Documents/Archived/Major%20Initiatives/Energy%20Efficiency/Multi-Residential%20Commercial%20and%20Public%20Buildings/Pdf/31227%20Power%20Factor%20Correction%20Evaluation.pdf) on power factor correction, we get the following snippet about power factor correction in the tenant spaces (offices, apartments) of a commercial building, vs. the utility parts (elevator lifts, HVAC):

> If we were to take an example of a typical commercial building, the
>   main switchboard is split  into two separate sections; a house
>   services section and a tenant section... *[snip]*
>
> The house section normally houses the circuit breakers for the central
>   air conditioning plant,  lifts, house lighting and power. As will be
>   highlighted in Section 7, motors account for a  decrease in power
>   quality and thus a reduction in power factor. In this particular
>   instance it  would be a valid exercise to consider the benefits of
>   power factor on this section of the  installation. In most instances
>   power factor correction is installed providing immediate cost  savings
>   to the base building owner.
>
> As the tenant power is on a separate bus, they also have the
>   opportunity to consider power  factor correction. In most instances
>   the tenant supply usually consists of general lighting and  power with
>   some supplementary air conditioning. **The power factor for these
>   installations is  generally greater than 0.90 and as such there is no
>   significant benefit in installation PFC units.**  In addition, these
>   tenants are usually metered at a kWh rate that does not consider the
>   power  factor of the installation for billing purposes.

The bulk of electricity in houses is used to either heat things up (space heaters, ovens, cooktops, water heaters) or cool things down (air conditioners, refrigerators.) These either have intrinsically good power factor (heating elements are resistive, i.e. p.f. 1.00) or they come with power factor correction in-built ([air conditioners.](http://www.aircosaver.com/support_techniques.php))

The things you measured are mostly electronic devices, so they have poor power factor, but they also don't draw much power compared to the heating/cooling devices listed above.

--

Contrast this with industrial sites, where a large part of the load is AC induction motors with rated power factors between 0.80 to 0.90 (and less than that if they're less than fully loaded.) There can be 10 MW worth of induction motors in a decent size plant - I know of ore crushing and grinding mills which are driven by a 10 MW induction motor **each**.

It is much more cost effective to target such induction motor installations before targeting consumers.

---

In response to Lord Loh.'s comments:

Consumers (and small businesses) generally have no incentive to improve power factor. In Australia, at least, billing is by kilowatt-hours (real power) and the power factor is not considered in the bill.

However, Ergon Energy (the distribution authority in Queensland, Australia) is trying to drive power factor correction in small businesses. They are doing this by offering incentive payments for businesses who want to participate.

The reason for pushing PFC to small businesses is **not** to increase efficiency, in the sense of saving a few dollars on the power bill, but rather to mitigate the **exorbitant** price of power at peak demand. [To wit](https://www.ergon.com.au/energy-conservation/demand-management/electricity-demand-trials/power-factor-correction-pilot-project):

> The aim of the Queensland Government funded project is to use incentive payments to reduce **peak demand** by a total 4.7 MVA, with subsequent customer savings and carbon emissions reduction.

Because of the way the electricity market works, at peak period the *marginal* price of electricity (the price for Ergon to buy "*one additional kilowatt*") can be in the range of $1,000/kWh.  So by shaving 4.7 MVA off the peak demand, they are actually saving thousands of dollars ($10,000? $100,000? $1,000,000?) *per day*.

With savings like that, offering businesses an incentive to voluntarily install PFC is a no-brainer.

There is also the nice effect of decreasing the MVA loading on infrastructure like transmission lines and transformers, so that Ergon can get the most capacity out of those assets before they need to be upgraded. Simplistically, deferring a $1M project by one year allows you to earn 5% interest on that $1M, so this is another significant saving.

Comment: Also, kind of implied in this answer: households don't make up any kind of significant part of the electrical power consumption on the large scale. Household lighting has a sub-single digit percentage and even in summertime when everybody's home with the AC on, household power consumption is still usually below 10%. And it's distributed among orders of magnitude more users. Administrating that many users for so little potential gain is deemed just not worth it.

Comment: Is that really true, @user36129 ? Wikipedia says that in 2008, 36.2% of electrical energy consumption in the US was residential. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_energy_consumption#Electricity_Final_Consumption_by_categories

(I agree with your broader point that it probably isn't worth the administrative costs.)

Comment: I'd also expect the residential power factors to be partially leading, partially trailing, and most certainly uncorrelated.

Comment: @DougMcClean ah, thanks for the wiki, I was wrong then. I guess I had the wrong statistic in my head. Also, MSalters, there is no real leading or trailing phase shift as a cause of residential power factor as most of the distortion (which would be a better term) is from switching power supplies, not from phase-shifted loads.

Comment: I have my doubts about PFC and savings to the customer. It appears to me that better PFC saves the Power Cos a lot of money. The Power Cos can bill the customers for Watts and not the VA (reactive power sent back). Unless the Co is fining for poor power factor, the customer seems to have no incentive to correct it. Do I have my facts wrong? Does PFC benefit the customer financially or otherwise?

Comment: http://www.hearneng.com/WhitePapers/Does%20Power%20Factor%20Correction%20Save%20Money.pdf - Mentions something on the lines of what I wrote in my last comment.

Comment: @LordLoh. : see edit above - some utility companies are pushing power factor correction for residential and small business consumers, but not for the reasons you think.

Answer (score 15):

Utilities *do* care about power factor to residential buildings, but hassling them about it is more trouble than it's worth due to the relatively light load compared to serious industrial customers.

Instead, the utilities hassle your legislators.  It is logistically easier and much more cost effective for them to get laws passed to require certain power factors from devices commonly used by residential customers than to try to enforce or charge for low power factors from those customers directly.  In the EU, for example, any electronic device drawing more than some specified amount of power (used to be around 70 W if I remember right, but I think the threshold has been lowered recently) must have a power factor above some limit to get CE certification.  More and more electronic devices start with switching power supplies that do active power factor control, partially as a result of such laws emerging worldwide.

Comment: Demanding PFC via law is the real answer on what is happenning here, especially in the EU, where heating with electricity is less common, and the incandescent light bulb is frowned up (via law).

Comment: @PlasmaHH: … frowned *upon*.

Answer (score 1):

Read the fine print from your power company. You're probably paying for apparent power already, not actual. So they don't care about your PF in residential scenarios.

Comment: That would require that the power meter measured kVAh rather than kWh. That would be easy to check by reading the units designation on the utiltiy meter. I'm not aware of anyone metering with kVAh only. What does your power company do?

Answer (score 0):

A hot subject and it will only get hotter! There are no good standards. Utilities did not bill small kVAR loads for two reasons.

- More trouble than it was worth
- and induction disc meters do not measure it

However switching power supplies, and there are many types, are used more and more and generate lower power factors. This puts the utility in a tough position as low power factor does cost the utility more. Utilities are trying to find ways to recoup some of these costs but raising kWh rates can be difficut for a regulated utility. One method that is pure fraud is to meter with a smart meter that only generates kVA numbers not kW numbers.